# How do I scale all images to a specific height in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, resize

I'm messing around with a character sorter javascript, learning a lot but I can't seem to find a way to scale all the images to a certain height (450 is the height I want). Only roundabout way I'm doing it is resizing each and every image, but that is tedious and I'm sure there's a better way.

Here's the code:

```
str_CenterT = 'Tie!';
str_CenterB = 'Undo last choice';

str_ImgPath = 'http://i.imgur.com/';
var bln_ResultMode = 1;
var int_ResultImg = 2;
var int_ResultRank = 3;


var bln_ResultStyle = 0;


var bln_ProgessBar = 1;


var int_Colspan = 2;
var ary_TitleData = [
   "Male",
   "Female",
];
var ary_CharacterData = [
   [1, "Calem",         [1,0], "kp5zFMC.png"],
   [1, "Leaf",      [0,1], "AYiQoyc.png"],
   [1, "Hilbert",       [1,0], "SAuywcW.png"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you solve this using CSS properties?

```
img.my-image {
    height: 450px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Adding that to the code doesn't work unfortunately. Anything I'm doing wrong? Or just adding that to the script is what I'm not suppose to do?

Comment: This is CSS. You need to place it in your stylesheet and assign the class name to your image element.

Comment: Don't know what any of that is. Is there any simpler way? Do you think you could give me any steps?